# Docker network bridge overlapping with IP addressing used for the VPN clients on the host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I deployed my app using docker-compose, it creates a default network bridge and this bridge interface overlaps with the IP address used for the VPN clients on the host. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a subnet to use when creating your docker network. You can even provide an `ip-range` from which to assign to your containers.

On the [documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) you can find this example:

```sh
docker network create \
  --driver=bridge \
  --subnet=172.28.0.0/16 \
  --ip-range=172.28.5.0/24 \
  --gateway=172.28.5.254 \
  br0
```

If you want to create your network inside your `docker-compose` file you have to define your own custom network, and configure it on each container.

Here is an example similar to the one provided in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - br0

networks:
  br0:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
        ip_range: 172.28.5.0/24
        gateway: 172.28.5.254
```

And here is a link to the [network configuration reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#network-configuration-reference) for more information.